# US Map Plugin Help Required

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, dictionary

I'm new to jQuery and using a U.S. map JQuery plugin for my project.

http://newsignature.github.io/us-map/

I successfully added the map to my web page. But I need 2 extra features which I'm not able to figure out how to do.

1) I want to display each state's abbreviation name on it.

2) I want a direct link to that state page by clicking on it. currently plugin map only display selected state.

here is the code for plugin, HTML Code,

```
<div id="map" style="width: 350px; height: 250px;"></div>
<div id="clicked-state"></div>
```

Javascript Code,

```
$('#map').usmap({
// The click action
click: function(event, data) {
$('#clicked-state')
.text('You clicked: '+data.name)
.parent().effect('highlight', {color: '#C7F464'}, 2000);
}
});
```

Anyone have experience using this map? Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: You might be better off contacting the author of the plugin. It maybe a feature that they might want to add.

Comment: For issue 1, Someone already did this. It's on Github as a pull request:
https://github.com/NewSignature/us-map/pull/16 I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector Drawing tool (like Inkscape) to add the Territory names to SVG file then replace the existing Blank_US_Map.svg

To implement the link behavior you want change

```
$('#map').usmap({
// The click action
click: function(event, data) {
      window.location.href = date.name+".html";
  }
});
```